# n is of the form 3(mod 4), prove n cannot be sum of two squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have looked across old past papers whilst revising and have stumbled across a question I have not seen before,

**Let $n$ be a positive integer of the form $3(\textrm{mod} \; 4)$, show that n cannot be written as the sum of two squares.**

I began by writing $$n=p_1^{a_1} {p_2^{a_2}} \cdot\cdot \cdot {p_k^{a_k}}.$$
Where $p$ is a prime number then I wrote $n=3+4t$, but I am not sure where to go from here, all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two squares or two primes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem

Comment: @labbhattacharjee that does not prove it, it just states it using a book which I cannot find, is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: @ericw31415 Apologies my mistake in the question, two squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to think in terms of prime factorization. If $m^2+n^2\equiv3\pmod 4$, then $m$ and $n$ can't be both even nor can they be both odd. Therefore, you can assume withou loss of generality that $m$ is odd and $n$ is even. If $m=2a+1$ and $n=2b$, with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, then$$m^2+n^2=4(a^2+a+b^2)+1\not\equiv3\pmod4.$$

Comment: Thankyou, was thinking about it completely wrong!

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit new to number theory. Why is it that $4(a^2 + a + b^2)$ cannot be congruent to 3 mod 4?

Comment: @Mailbox I did *not* write that. What I wrote was that $4(a^2+a+b^2)\color{red}{+1}\not\equiv3\pmod4$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Right, that’s what I meant to write, my apologies. Why is that expression never equal to 3 mod 4?

Comment: @Mailbox Asserting that $a\equiv b\pmod 4$ means that $4\mid a-b$. But$$4(a^2+a+b^2)+1-3=4(a^2+a+b^2)-2,$$which is not a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & x^2 \pmod 4\\
0 & 0\\
1 & 1\\
2 & 0\\
3 & 1\end{array}\quad$ So the sum of two squares can be $\{0,1,2\}\pmod 4$ but never $3$.