# No primitive pythagorean triple $(x,y,z)$ with $z\equiv -1 \pmod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Show that there are no primitive pythagorean triple $(x,y,z)$ with $z\equiv -1 \pmod 4$.

I once have proven that, for all integers $a,b$, we have that $a^2 + b^2$ is congruent to $0$, or $1$, or $2$ modulo $4$. I feel like it is enough to conclude it by considering $a=x$, $b=y$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1$. But I am not completely sure if it is the way the proof should end.

Comment: Are you aware of the classification of primitive Pythagorean triples?

Comment: This is a subpart of Fermat's theorem on the sum of squares. I am trying to master each part of this theorem and have been working through it's sections while using: 
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares
As a guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [n is of the form 3(mod 4), prove n cannot be sum of two squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749025/n-is-of-the-form-3mod-4-prove-n-cannot-be-sum-of-two-squares)

Comment: You certainly do have to use the hypothesis of primitivity: consider the nonprimitive triple $(9,12,15)$. Have you applied primitivity in your proof?

Comment: "I once have proven that, for all integers a,b, we have that a2+b2 is congruent to 0, or 1, or 2 "  So $z$ *squared* is congruent 0, 1 or 2, but $z$ itself, could still be $-1\mod 4$.  Example.  $9^2 + 12^2 = 15^2$ and $15 \equiv -1 \mod 4$.   But $9,12,15$ isn't primitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have proven for all integers $a, b$ this property holds, then yes it follows immediately that it holds for the subset of those integer pairs for which $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Comment: S/he's proven that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \not \equiv -1 \mod 4$ but he has not proven that $z \not\equiv -1 \mod 4$.

Comment: Example: $9^2 + 12^2 = 81 + 144 = 225=15^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ but $15\equiv -1 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive  Pythagorean triples can be exhaustively generated using the relationships $x=m^2-n^2, y=2mn, z=m^2+n^2$ for positive integers $m>n,gcd(m,n=1),m\not\equiv n\mod{2}$. You can check this out by substituting those relationships in the Pythagorean formula $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and seeing that they add up correctly.

The modularity condition means that one of $(m,n)$ is odd and the other is even. Wlog let $m$ be even and $n$ be odd. Then $m^2\equiv 0\mod{4}$ and $n^2\equiv 1\mod{4}$. Hence $m^2+n^2\equiv 1\mod{4}$; or $m^2+n^2(=z)\not\equiv -1\mod{4}$.